# Set an image width to the screen width and the height of the original image height (LIKE INSTAGRAM) in react-native

Tags: react-native

I want to implement like instagram to show the images/video on full width of the device and the original image height. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put the image with width as device width and height as device height. Then specify the `resizeMode` property to `contain`. This will make the whole image fit the screen.

```js
<Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: img_url }} />;
```

image style,

```js
const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');
```

```js
image: {
  width,
  height,
  resizeMode: 'contain'
},
```

Or check this [Live Snack Example](https://snack.expo.dev/@nithinpp69/image-viewer)

Comment: I have seen so many convoluted ways to do this, why don't people do it this way? There must be a catch! If not - thank you so much!